# What is the technically correct term for an instance of class which implements IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, terminology, ienumerable

Do we call such an instance a "collection"? An "enumerable"? Or something else? I ask with my two main goals being:

1. To be understood by other developers, without having to explain that the class implements `IEnumerable`.
2. To be technically correct and precise.

Comment: +1 never even thought about it ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be technically precise, I would inform developers that it implements IEnumerable.

To say anything else is being less informative.

Anyone who understands IEnumerable will immediately understand the capabilities of your class. Anyone who doesn't, wouldn't get it however you described it.

Answer (score 6):

> An "enumerable"?

This is a pretty widely accepted answer; I'd recommend against calling it a collection, because that might imply that the object implements `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Very precise. `IEnumerable` can even not be a collection, especially in light of `yield` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

There is none, so I would use the phrase "an enumerable type".

A collection is something that contains a finite number of items. A enumerable type is not necessarily a collection because it can be an infinite list.

A list is a collection that has a definite order.

Comment: "An enumerable type" is too easily confused with an `enum` type, so I try to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific term for it, although most classes that implement `IEnumerable` are collections. A notable exception is `String`, but it can be seen as a collection of characters...

Answer (score 2):

I usually just say "I have this IEnumerable..." and that seems enough at work and at SO. It clearly expresses that I'm talking about a class that implements IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with those suggesting "<strike>enumerator</strike>enumerable", but if you want something else, the term "sequence" would also work.

Comment: I wouldn't use "enumerator" because I would assume that an enumerator implements IEnumerator, not IEnumerable. I do like "sequence". We often call the methods like Where, Select, Max and so on the "sequence operators".

Comment: Sorry--I meant "enumerable" but misspoke.  My intention was to offer up the term "sequence", while expressing agreement with those who use the term "enumerable".

Comment: The `System.Linq.Enumerable` static class  was also originally called `Sequence`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling it by "an IEnumerable" would be completely appropriate. This makes it very apparent that it the class implements IEnumerable, and is brief and precise.

From an object-oriented standpoint, this class IS-AN IEnumerable, so again, this is justified.

Comment: Thanks for emphasizing the *IS* aspect of interfaces.  Since interfaces define substitutability, they express an "is-a" rather than "has-a" relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The ObservableCollection class calls it a "collection".

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>
    //     class that contains elements copied from the specified collection.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   collection:
    //     The collection from which the elements are copied.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The collection parameter cannot be null.
    public ObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "An Enumeration".

This technically means the result of enumerating, but that is generally how an IEnumerable interface is perceived.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that IEnumerable and the word "enumerable" is not a noun.  You say `"something is enumerable"`, not `"something is an enumerable"`.  Put another way, an object being enumerable is something you do with the object, not a definition of the object itself.

MSDN describes it as:

> IEnumerable - Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type.

To be precise when documenting I would use:

> "List<int> is an enumerable collection of System.Int32 values."

Comment: I would avoid applying the term "collection" to something which is known only as an IEnumerable, so as to avoid confusion with Collection and ICollection, substituting the term "type", "instance", or perhaps "entity" as appropriate.  Actually, perhaps the best term for an object known only to implement IEnumerable is to simply call it "an IEnumerable". I would describe which implements a duck-typable GetEnumerator but does not implement IEnumerable as a "for-each-able entity".

Comment: @supercat Agreed - You probably want to avoid entity too as it also has a specific meaning. Instance implies a concrete, and it may be abstract - so I think you're either stuck with Type or something more verbose.

Comment: @Basic: Perhaps the rather blah-sounding "thing"?  Though actually, the terms "type", "storage location", "constraint", or "instance" would probably be better in cases where they're applicable.  It's worth noting, btw, that the semantics of different kinds of things vary depending upon which of the above they are.  For example, a storage location which is declared as an interface type allocates space for an object reference.  Always.  On the other hand, a storage location of generic type which is constrained to an interface may hold a struct instead.

Comment: @supercat I hadn't even considered that - you're right. Far murkier than at first glance